# Getting NoSuchFile or Directory in subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to run a CLI tool using `subprocess.run()`, but i'm getting irrelevant responses.

**Folder structure**

```
script.py

mytools
 |__tool_x
 |__tool_y
```

**Case:1**
Try to run the below command

```py
import os
import subprocess

command = ["mytools/tool_x", "--help"]

subprocess.run(
                 command,
                 stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                 cwd=os.path.dirname(__file__),
             )
```

**Result:** It works as expected, gives no error.

**Case-2:**

```py
import os
import subprocess

command = ["mytools/tool_x", "--subcommand", "test", "--subarg"]

subprocess.run(
                 command,
                 stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                 cwd=os.path.dirname(__file__),
             )
```

**Result:** Fails with `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mytools/tool_x'"`

How can i resolve this, not able to find the issue, generally what are the possibilities for this issue?

Comment: Are both commands run from the parent of the “mytools” directory?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the question is how can i resolve the error?

Comment: @MarkTolonen yes the commands run from the parent of mytools directory

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your error: both cases work fine. You should comment out the `stdout=` line and see what output it produces.